# Kerberos Ticket From Apache to Tomcat (Windows)

Tags: apache, tomcat, kerberos

i have a web-application on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

The application is using Kerberos for SSO.

If i use only Tomcat everything is working fine.

But if i use an Apache in front of Tomcat the ticket seems to be wrong.

Instead of the AD-User the server from the web-application is logging in.

Is there any configuration in Apache to handle the Kerberos ticket correctly?

If you need any more informations just let me know.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't have try anything so far, because im fairly new to apache and Kerberos. I have a web.xml in my application for all the kerberos information. I looked for any settings in apache for kerberos but couldn't find anything